# sql to find inbetween values

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
 A       B
-----------
 1.2     2.3
 2.3     3.9
 3.9     4.34
 4.34    5.786
```

what the data means is that 1.2-5.786 is the length of some table and 
1.2-2.3 has some attributes
2.3-3.9 has some attributes and so on... but 1.2 - 5.786 when you consider it is the length of entire table(for example here).

I want to run a query which would give me rows between two values: for example:

A =1.1 amd B = 4.234

I am having hard time to figure out how to write a query, most of the queries I write leave out some edge cases.

Comment: if `A=1.1 and B=4.234`, what answer are you expecting?

Comment: I am trying to get all the rows in between those values like when a =1.3 and b = 4.234 i want the first three rows. since a = 1.3 is between 1.2 and 2.3 of the first row and b = 4.234 is between 3.9 and 4.34 in the third row. so i want the first three rows in my result set.

Comment: Given the range (1.1, 4.234), you want to find all values in the table where the range overlaps the given range.  The primary tricky part is 'branching the right way on equality', but you have an answer that works.  See also: [Determine whether two date ranges overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap/); the logic applies to any ranges, not just date ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work well:

```
select *
from yourtable
where (b > 1.1 and a <= 4.234)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76dfa0/1)

Basically make sure b is greater than the lower bound and a is less than or equal to the upper bound.  Depending on your desired results, you may need to change `b >` to `b >=`.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want the values between `A =1.1 amd B = 4.234` then the output is

```
  A       B
```

---

```
1.2         2.3

2.3         3.9
```

then the query is:

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE A>=1.1 AND B<=4.234
```

But if you want the output

```
  A       B
```

---

```
1.2         2.3

2.3         3.9

3.9         4.34
```

Then you want the query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE A >= 1.1 AND A < 4.234 B > 4.234
```

Comment: what if a= 1.3 then A>=1.3 will skip the first row but 1.3 is between 1.2 and 2.3 which is te first row.

Comment: Then your question is badly defined.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT a, b
  FROM my_table 
  WHERE A >= 1.1 AND B <= 4.234
     OR A >= 1.1 AND A <  4.234 
     OR B >  1.1 AND B <= 4.234
```

This assumes A is always < B